# join inbox and sent box table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating message conversation script in PHP mysqli. I have two table inbox and sent box, this two table same columns I want to join this two table.and i want to get last message between two users.

inbox table

```
id  from_id     to_id    msg               sent_date
1   2           3        hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3           2        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2           3        hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5           2        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

sentbox table

```
id  from_id     to_id    msg               sent_date
1   2           3        hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3           2        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2           3        hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5           2        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

Here is my source code

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}
$sql = "SELECT *,
    (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=from_id) AS from_username,
    (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=to_id) AS to_username,
    (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=?) AS my_username,
    (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=from_id) AS from_profile_pic,
    (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=to_id) AS to_profile_pic,
    (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=?) AS my_profile_pic
    FROM inbox WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $session_id, $session_id, $session_id, $session_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT * from inbox i 
inner join sentbox s on i.from_id = s.to_id  
inner join users u on u.user_id = i.from_id
where i.from_id = 'your desired id here'
order by i.sent_date DESC limit 1;
```

I believe this would give you the latest communication between 2 users.

Having said that, it feels like it would be better to go with a simpler design where every communication is a transaction and you store it in a single table, with FROM and TO fields and the time of the communication. No need to do a JOIN between 2 tables here. You're duplicating data here.

Comment: I want to join two table if not i cant delete messages what should i do for that help me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment above. My suggestion (unless you have a specific need for this data model) is to have the transactions in a single table.